# Is it possible to debug multiple codebases running in Firebase functions emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, vscode-debugger, firebase-tools

I'm trying to debug some Firebase Functions running locally with the Firebase Emulator and VS Code.

I can do that with the following command:

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

"Debugger is listening on `ws://127.0.0.1:9229/{some-uuid}`" then I can attach VS Code to it.

The problem is that I'm running **2** codebases in the same emulator, but the debugger can start only once... so I can only debug the first codebase defined in *firebase.json*.

Is it possible to change the **9229** port in order to run another debugger (in the same, or in another emulator)?

Comment: I could find a workaround by running a second emulator with a specific port numer: `firebase --config=firebase-part2.json emulators:start --inspect-functions 9230` but I'm not sure it's the best way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're encountering issues with debugging multiple Firebase functions codebases, here's a workaround that might help.

First, locate your `firebase-tools` installation folder. This folder is typically installed globally within your Node.js installation. For those using NVM (Node Version Manager) on Windows, you can usually find it at `C:\Progs\nvm\v20.10.0\node_modules\firebase-tools\`.

**Modifications Needed:**

1. **In `firebase-tools\lib\emulator\controller.js`:**

   - Find the line containing `codebase:`.
   - After `codebase: cfg.codebase,`, insert a new line: `inspectorPort: cfg.inspectorPort,`.
   - The result should look like this:

     ```js
     emulatableBackends.push({
         functionsDir,
         runtime,
         codebase: cfg.codebase,
         inspectorPort: cfg.inspectorPort,
         env: Object.assign({}, options.extDevEnv),
         secretEnv: [],
         predefinedTriggers: options.extDevTriggers,
     });
     ```
2. **In `firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulator.js`:**

   - Search for `${this.args.debugPort}`.
   - Replace it with `${backend.inspectorPort || this.args.debugPort}`.
   - This ensures that `inspectorPort` from the configuration is used if specified, otherwise it defaults to the port from command-line arguments or the default port.

After these changes, your Firebase Tools installation should now support specifying separate ports for each codebase.

**Further Configuration:**

- In your `firebase.json` file, add `"inspectorPort": "9230",` to each codebase entry. Ensure you use unique ports for different codebases.
- Modify your `launch.json` file to include a new debugger setting for each codebase, specifying the appropriate ports.

With these steps completed, when you start the emulators, you should be able to attach debugger instances to the different functions codebases for effective debugging. Happy coding!

Comment: It might be beneficial for the Firebase development team to consider incorporating these modifications in a future release. If anyone knows the appropriate channels or individuals to tag for this suggestion, it could help in bringing this improvement to the wider Firebase community. @frank-van-puffelen

Comment: Great solution... Thank you very much!
On mypart I found the module in C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: I opened an issue because I cannot (or don't know how to) create a PR. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6817